# How to RANK rows in Sheets with two columns matching criteria

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, rank, formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to Rank employees with exact **site** and **job titles** in a list of a few hundred rows using google sheets. So, like location C123 and SET should have RANK by **Classification Seniority Date** for those matches, then C123 and SEA should also have a separate RANK for that group, etc. (Company Seniority is the tie breaker)

I hope this makes sense. I do have a sample sheet to share to someone that might know what I'm trying to do.

```
EMPLID  Job Title    Abbrev  Cl Sen Date  Rank  CoSenDate  Location
119870  Sp Ed Techn    SET    09/05/88     1    07/08/77   C123
119232  Sp Ed Techn    SET    10/06/97     2    10/02/95   C123
155422  Sp Ed Techn    SET    09/07/99     3    02/15/96   C123
153431  Sp Ed Asst     SEA    01/03/00     1    01/03/00   C123
170736  Sp Ed Techn    SET    09/25/02     4    09/07/99   C123
155626  Sp Ed Asst     SEA    10/25/04     2    10/25/04   C123
162437  Security Asst  CSA    09/08/05     1    10/03/02   C123
113541  Sp Ed Techn    SET    09/25/09     5    09/25/09   C123
124576  Sp Ed Techn    SET    05/04/15     6    05/04/15   C123
110294  Sp Ed Asst     SEA    10/12/17     3    10/12/17   C123
```

I've tried VLOOKUP, etc, but have had no luck and using the ARRAYFORMULA function REALLY overtaxed my computer to the point that it took a couple of minutes or so to let me finally undo what I tried...

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Thanks for looking. Sorting is not my problem. I'm trying to rank by Cl Sen Date but grouped by Location and Job Title. So, basically like: Location1, Job Title 1, Rank group... then Location 1, Job Title 2, Rank group... Location 2, Job Title 1, Rank group, etc... I've tried lots of things but either they just are wrong, or tie up my computer in what seems like an endless loop and usually have to restart the page I'm working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most people consider RANK an individual function but it is for all intents and purposes just a COUNTIF. Expand to a COUNTIFS to add additional criteria.

```
=IF(C2="SET", COUNTIFS(C$2:C$11, C2, G$2:G$11, G2, F$2:F$11, "<="&F2), TEXT(,))
'full column alternate
=IF(C2="SET", COUNTIFS(C:C, C2, G:G, G2, F:F, "<="&F2), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Comment: vba habits rearing themselves. I hate doubling up quotes within quoted strings so I use text(,) instead of "" whenever possible.

Comment: I get zeroes at times which confuses me. Here is the link to the sample sheet to look at. Thanks!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SKtnFwQ5FE3B1Yy6cDZ9UPbwfXrFT8PVu6-PypXJJ6k/edit?usp=sharing